# Why can't I drive pin RA4 low on PIC16F1823?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplabx, xc8

I am using PIC16F1823 MCU.  Pin RA4 is a multipurpose pin but can be used as I/O.  But I cannot find which settings are required to achieve this.  I've tried to disable all unrequired peripherals associated with the pin, in the setup code (MPLABX 5.40, XC8) below, but the pin remains at VDD and does not respond to an instruction to go low.  What is it I'm missing?

```c
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin is input)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)
// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = ON       // PLL Enable (4x PLL enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)

#include <xc.h>

void device_setup(void) {
    // Peripherals
    ANSELA = 0x00;              // set analogue port A off
    ANSELC = 0x00;              // set analogue port C off
    CM1CON0 = 0x80;             // disable comparators
    CM2CON0 = 0x80;             // disable comparators
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1M = 0x0;    // disable ECCP module
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 0x0;    // disable MSSP module
         
    // Timer - required by NEC RX
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b1110;   // oscillator HFINTOSC @ 8 MHz with PLL = 32 MHz
    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 1;     // Disable prescaler
    OPTION_REGbits.TMR0CS = 0;  // TMR0 is timer (not counter) on instruction clock
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;      // Clear the Timer 0 interrupt flag
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;      // Enable the Timer 0 interrupt    
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         // Set the Global Interrupt Enable
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;       // Disable Timer 1
    T1GCONbits.TMR1GE = 0;      // Disable Timer 1 gate control
    MDCONbits.MDEN = 0;         // Disable modulator
    MDCONbits.MDOE = 0;         // Disable modulator output pin
    
    // PORT
    WPUA = 0b00111111;          // All PORTA pins weak pull-up enabled
    WPUC = 0b00111111;          // All PORTC pins weak pull-up enabled
    OPTION_REGbits.nWPUEN = 0;  // Global enable weak pull-ups
    
    // GPIO
    TRISA2 = GPIO_INPUT;        // RX is input
    TRISA0 = GPIO_OUTPUT;       // USART TX is output
    TRISA4 = GPIO_OUTPUT;       // MOTOR_FWD is output 
    TRISA5 = GPIO_OUTPUT;       // MOTOR_REV is output
    TRISC2 = GPIO_OUTPUT;       // RX LED is output
    TRISC1 = GPIO_OUTPUT;       // TX LED is output
    TRISA3 = GPIO_INPUT;        // OPEN_SENS is input
    TRISC5 = GPIO_INPUT;        // CLOSE_SENS is input
}
```

[Microchip PIC16F1823 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001413e.pdf)

Comment: Are you writing to LATA4 or RA4? Did you try another chip?

Comment: I'm writing to RA4 - I could of course try another chip

Comment: Identical results on the second chip

Comment: It's better to write to the latch (and read from RA4).

Comment: Yes, that's the solution, thank you - would you like to submit that as an answer so I can accept it and vote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always write to the latch (LATA4 in this case) and read from RA4, otherwise you can have issues because of the [read-modify-write problem](http://www.piclist.com/techref/readmodwrite.htm) with writing to RA4, depending on what is connected to the pin and on timing.

An instruction such as BSF, RA4 can also affect other pins in the same port since the actual pin states for the entire byte are read, RA4 is modified, and then it is written to the byte-wide PORTA latch. If the pin states are not the same as the latch for some reason, the other pin states can change, which is probably not what you want.